# Count rows, which have not blank cells

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

`COUNTIF(range,"<>")` function allows us to count cells, which are not blank. But how to count rows, which are not blank?

I have a range `A1:C100`, some cells in this range are blank and some are not blank. I want to count a row when and only when it has at least one non blank cell in one of the tree columns.

P.S. I'm using googledocs.

Answer (score 1):

If you have `Office 365`:

`=SUM(N(MMULT(N(range<>""),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(range))^0)>0))`

Otherwise, array formula (`CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER`):

`=SUM(N(MMULT(N(range<>""),TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(range))^0)>0))`

Comment: OP can still use this in GS `=INDEX(SUM(N(MMULT(N(A1:C100<>""),{1,1,1})>0)))`. +

Comment: @JvdV Sure, but `{1,1,1}` would need to be `{1;1;1}` for English language versions (we've been here before! :-)). And of course that's static, as opposed to dynamic, which is ok if the OP is certain that there'll never be more than 3 columns to consider.

Comment: Lol yes, I just keep forgetting the English notation.

Answer (score 0):

In GS you could alternatively try:

```
=INDEX(SUM(N(TRIM(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(A1:C100),,9^9))<>"")))
```